# Physically based camera values too small

Tags: c++, opengl, math, camera, physics

I am currently working on a physically based camera model and came across this blog: https://placeholderart.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/implementing-a-physically-based-camera-manual-exposure/
So I tried to implement it myself in OpenGL. I thought of calculating the exposure using the function getSaturationBasedExposure and pass that value to a shader where I will multiply the final color with that value:

```
float getSaturationBasedExposure(float aperture,
                             float shutterSpeed,
                             float iso)
{
    float l_max = (7800.0f / 65.0f) * Sqr(aperture) / (iso * shutterSpeed);
    return 1.0f / l_max;
}



colorOut = color * exposure;
```

But the values I get from that function are way too small (like around 0.00025 etc) so I guess I am missunderstanding the returned value of that function.
In the blog a test scene is mentioned in which the scene luminance is around 4000, but I haven't seen a shader implementation working with color range from 0 to 4000+ (not even HDR goes that high, right?).

So could anyone explain me how to apply the calculations correctly to a OpenGL scene or help me understand the meaning behind the calculations?

Comment: Your `color` will have to be a physical luminance.

Comment: So you mean the color value should be in a range of 0 to 4000 and above? Is this best practise or should I divide/multiply all values by i.e. 1000 before passing them to the shader, so values are more in a common range?

Comment: You need a physical rendering pipeline for this. I.e. lights should have proper luminous intensities etc. The whole exposure stuff is then just a way of mapping photogrammetric quantities to pixel values.

Comment: @NicoSchertler could you provide a simple sample or any article/source? I couldn't find any targeting this specific theme